# Run a command on all the files in a directory tree and put the output into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, files, recursive, command-substitution

I want to run this bash command :

```
#!/bin/bash
rep="*"

for f in `ls -R`$rep; do
d='git log '$f'| wc -l'
c=$d
echo $c
done
```

how to excute a command `git log myFile | wc -l` from bash ?

ps : this command will return a number : `git log myFile | wc -l`

Comment: See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) regarding your `$d` variable.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs?highlight=%28parse%29%7C%28ls%29) regarding the use of `ls`.

Comment: Really? You seems to know the back tick already, why are you asking about it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute a command and get the output use the line below

```
d=`git log`
```

In your script you have to change two two things. I have the correct script below

```
#!/bin/bash
rep="*"

for f in `ls -R $rep`; do
d=`git log $f| wc -l`
c=$d
echo $c
done
```

Edit: The original correction is changing the quotes to backticks to make the output reach the d variable.
In addition, the $rep should be inside the backticks with the ls, otherwise it will add the * at the end of the last file name processed.

Comment: Yes it works, i have a same result when i run `eval` commande :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've already answered your other question [Syntax error in a bash script that calls find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50456/syntax-error-in-a-bash-script-that-calls-find), so I won't repeat what I already wrote in [my answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50536).

[Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You don't need to run `ls` to enumerate files in a directory. Use `find` if you need to recurse into subdirectories.

To get the output of `wc -l`, use it in a command substitution: `$(git log "$f" | wc -l)`

Note that you need double quotes around the variable name. Always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`. Double quotes turn off the shell's further processing of the value of the variable or command output: without quotes, the result is split into words which are interpreted as file wildcard patterns. With single quotes, the `$` sign is not treated specially, so `git` would see `$f` instead of the value.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for x in "$@"; do
    c=$(git log "$f" | wc -l)
  done
' _ {} +
```

The use of `-exec … {} +` instead of `-exec … {} \;` allows the intermediate shell to be invoked only once per large batch of files, which is a bit faster.

Since bash ≥4, you don't need to use `find`, you can use the `**` syntax to recurse into subdirectories.

```
shopt -s globstar
for x in **/*; do
  [ -f "$x" ] || continue  # skip directories and other non-regular files
  git log "$x" | wc -l
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the command  :

```
     git log
```

Will show all the revision histories. If that is true, i guess you are trying to store the contents inside a file called myfile and then you want to count the no of lines in the file.

If this is what you want, first you can save the history in this way:

```
     git log>myFile.txt
```

Now you need to find the no of lines using wc -l and store it a file called nOfLines.txt

So you have to do this :

```
    wc -l<myFile.txt>nOfLines.txt
```

Then store the content of this file inside a variable called gitVar.

```
     gitVar=$(cat nOfLines.txt)
```

You can see whether this is working properly using this command :

```
     echo "$gitVar"
```

Just bundle the whole thing inside a script called "myCommand.sh", give it permssions using chmod a+x and run the script from the terminal like a command.

Comment: You may prefer `wc -l < myFile.txt > nOfLines.txt` instead to avoid `wc` mentioning the input file's name in its output.

Comment: @manatwork : yes, tx for pointing it out.

Comment: You can not have spaces around `=` in the assignment: `gitVar=$(cat nOfLines.txt)`.

Comment: @manatwork: Ahhh, another blunder by me. Okay edited the ans as per all your suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, i think with a commande `eval` :D

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
rep="*"

for f in `ls -R`$rep; do
d='git log "$f"| wc -l'
c=$d
echo $c
done
```

Notice the double quotes instead of the single ones around git command.

A smaller solution could be to use:

```
echo `git log "$f"| wc -l`
```

Comment: No with your commande i have the same result as my script. In addition you have a mistake in your script :)

Comment: I am really sorry. I had an extra quote. Please try now and upvote it if it works for you.

Comment: i corrected it and i have the same result !