# Syntax error in a bash script that calls find

Tags: bash, find, quoting

Where is the error in this script please:

```
#!/bin/bash
rep="git"

files=`find' ${rep} '-type f`
for f in ${files} do
    echo $f
done
```

When i run `find git -type f` alone in the shell, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes from

```
files=`find '$rep' -type f`
```

The correct script is

```
#!/bin/bash
rep="git"

files=`find $rep -type f`
for f in ${files}; do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: Supposing you have no file names containing `IFS` characters.

Answer (score 6):

Strings in single quotes are not interpolated. It means, you are trying to run

```
find ' ${rep} '-type f
```

Remove the single quotes. If you really need to quote the $rep (e.g. because it contains spaces), use double quotes:

```
files=`find "$rep" -type f`
```

Note that there are no spaces inside the double quotes. You are searching 'git', not ' git ', right?

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the output of `find` in a variable. It's unreliable and inefficient. Inefficient, because `find` has to finish running before you start processing its output; this makes a difference on a large directory tree. Unreliable because even if you got the command syntax right, the output of `find` would consists of a list of file names separated by newlines. This is ambiguous unless the file names are known not to contain newlines. Furthermore, you aren't parsing the output correctly: with an unquoted command substitution `$(…)`, the result of the command is broken into separate words wherever there's whitespace (not just newlines), and the words are interpreted as shell glob patterns. To avoid this processing, use `"$(…)"` (always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions: `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`); this is no good here since you need to separate the file names.

`find` has a built-in feature to process the resulting files: the `-exec` action. Use it. That's what it's for.

```
find "$rep" -type f -exec echo {} \;
```

If you need to run an arbitrary shell snippet and not just a single command on each file, invoke a shell as the command. To avoid mangling the file name, pass it as a parameter to the shell.

```
find "$rep" -type f -exec sh -c '
  echo "$0"
  # more shell commands ...
' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add space after `'` and before `-type`